# UIImageView web images are not displayed on XCode 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, xcode7

Today I have moved my project to XCode 7 from XCode 6. Before it was working perfect but now I ve some weird issues.

I am displaying image on UIImageView and that image is downloaded from web. Here is the code:

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [cell.imgTrainer setImage:image];
        selectedTrainerImage = image;
    });
});
```

I have checked `imageURL` and it is fine.

I am calling the page with `presentViewController`

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UIViewController* controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TrainerListView"];

self.animationController = [[ZoomAnimationController alloc] init];

controller.transitioningDelegate  = self;
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I dont understand what is the problem. I didn't touch even a line what was working on XCode 6.

Comment: Is it HTTPS? Might be because of App Transport Security ( https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/ )

Comment: This is another good example why not to use the `WithContentsOfURL:` methods. Use `NSURLSession` because there is no way to detect download errors on `WithContentsOfURL:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For temporary you can add key to plist.But its not safe.

http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/

`<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>`

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To resolve you issue with App Transport Security you have two options:

- Make the API work through HTTPS
- Paste this line of code into your `info.plist` and continue to use your app as you used to before the upgrade to Xcode 7:

  `<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
      <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
  </dict>`